# Logstash Conf | Extracting Filename from Path

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am trying to setup Logstash to feed Elasticsearch. In course, I've created the following *conf* file that seem to work nicely:

```json
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
  
  file {
    path => "C:/f1/f2/Logs/f3/LocalHost#base#iway_2022-03-28T10_45_15.log"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => {
      "message" => [
        ".%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timeStamp}. %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} .(W.)%{DATA:thread}.%{INT:thread_pool}. %{GREEDYDATA:msgbody}",
        ".%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timeStamp}. %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} .%{DATA:thread}. %{GREEDYDATA:msgbody}"      
      ]
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https://localhost:9200"]
    index => "iway_logs"
    user => "elastic"
    password => "something"
    cacert => "C:\f1\f2\logstash-8.1.3\config\cert\elasticsearch_http_ca.crt"
  }
}
```

I have been trying to add two new fields but unsuccessful so far. Following is the current version of the *conf* file after several revises.

```json
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
  
  file {
    path => "C:/f1/f2/Logs/f3/LocalHost#base#iway_2022-03-28T10_45_15.log"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => {
      "message" => [
        ".%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timeStamp}. %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} .(W.)%{DATA:thread}.%{INT:thread_pool}. %{GREEDYDATA:msgbody}",
        ".%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timeStamp}. %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} .%{DATA:thread}. %{GREEDYDATA:msgbody}"      
      ]
    }
  }
  grok {
        match => { 
            "path" => "%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA:filename}\.log"
            }
  }
  mutate {
        split => { "filename" => "#" }
        add_field => { "serverName" => "%{[filename][0]}" }
        add_field => { "configName" => "%{[filename][1]}" }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https://localhost:9200"]
    index => "iway_logs"
    user => "elastic"
    password => "something"
    cacert => "C:\f1\f2\logstash-8.1.3\config\cert\elasticsearch_http_ca.crt"
  }
}
```

The result of new fields namely, serverName and configName, always reports the raw expression as opposed to an evaluated output. Could someone help? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably leverage the [`dissect` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-dissect.html) for that, like this:

```
filter {
  if [path] {
    dissect {
      mapping => {
       "path" => "C:/f1/f2/Logs/f3/%{serverName}#%{configName}#%{?ignore}.log"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you have [ECS compatibility enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-ecs_compatibility), the `path` field is called `[log][file][path]`, so your config should be this one instead:

```
filter {
  if [log][file][path] {
    dissect {
      mapping => {
       "[log][file][path]" => "C:/f1/f2/Logs/f3/%{serverName}#%{configName}#%{?ignore}.log"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This did not work. I see the following warning in logs:

`Dissector mapping, field not found in event {"field"=>"path",....`

Comment: I fixed my answer, this was because the events coming from the `beats` input don't have a `path` field, only the ones from the `file` input

Comment: thanks, the warning vanished but the requirement is not fulfilled. This was a test using file input. Introducing an IF statement just bypasses the dissect operation completely, thereby not serving the purpose...

Comment: Not sure I understand... that means you don't have any file input but only a beats one? If yes, what's the name of the field containing the file name? Simply remove the if condition and change the field name in the dissect filter

Comment: I mean, I've always been testing only with file. I have not gotten to beats mode of testing yet...

Comment: Then, you'll need to replace `path` by whatever field name comes through your beats input... `path` is created by the `file` input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244433/discussion-between-srii-and-val).